# cannot load image into Mat opencv

Tags: android, opencv, mat

I want load image with Mat class on android opencv but i have some errors.
I add library on my project.
 my code:
    private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;
    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                    mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                } break;
                default:
                {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                } break;
            }
        }
    };

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_6, this, mLoaderCallback);
}



 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.HelloOpenCvView);
     mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
     mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
     if (!OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_9, this, mLoaderCallback))
     {
       Log.e(TAG, "Cannot connect to OpenCV Manager");
     }
     else
         Log.i(TAG, "Load it"); 

     Mat Image = Highgui.imread("/mnt/sdcard/1.jpg");

 }

 @Override
 public void onPause()
 {
     super.onPause();
     if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
         mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
 }

 public void onDestroy() {
     super.onDestroy();
     if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
         mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
 }

 public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
 }

 public void onCameraViewStopped() {
 }


public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {  
    return inputFrame.rgba();
}
```

Log:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't use *any* opencv code in onCreate()

the so's with opencv's native code are not loaded yet, you will have to wait, until mLoaderCallback *finishes*.

so, move any operation on Mat to onCameraViewStarted()